# Insert Stored procedure to insert data into two tables at a time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to write a SP for SQL Server 2008 to insert data into two tables

`Login(username,password,id)` and `UserInfo(id,first_name,last_name,phone_no,email,address,IsActive)`.

`UserInfo` table requires that `id` should be entered which will be automatically generated in Login table while inserting new record. How should I construct this SP please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scope_identity() to catch the id being inserted into dbo.Login.
Like this:

```
drop table if exists dbo.UserInfo;
drop table if exists dbo.Login;


create table dbo.Login (
    id int not null identity (1, 1) primary key
    , username varchar(100)
    , password varchar(100)
);

create table dbo.UserInfo (
    id int not null primary key foreign key references dbo.Login(id)
    , first_name varchar(100)
    , last_name varchar(100)
    , phone_no varchar(100)
    , email varchar(100)
    , address varchar(100)
    , IsActive bit
);
go


create or alter procedure dbo.InsertIntoLoginAndUserInfo
(
    @username varchar(100)
    , @password varchar(100)
    , @first_name varchar(100)
    , @last_name varchar(100)
    , @phone_no varchar(100)
    , @email varchar(100)
    , @address varchar(100)
    , @IsActive bit
)
as

begin

    declare @id int;

    insert into dbo.Login (username, password)
    values (@username, @password);
    set @id = scope_identity();

    insert into dbo.UserInfo (id, first_name, last_name, phone_no, email, address, IsActive)
    values (@id, @first_name, @last_name, @phone_no, @email, @address, @IsActive);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function, which will return the last inserted identity column in the same scope.

You can read more about it here: [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql).

Your code inside the stored procedure would be something like:

```
DECLARE @NewlyInsertedID INT
INSERT INTO Login(UserName, Password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password)
SELECT @NewlyInsertedID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

INSERT INTO UserInfo (ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo, email, Address, IsActive) 
VALUES (@NewlyInsertedID, ,,, etc other columns )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one transaction using INSERT OUTPUT:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2183/using-insert-output-in-a-sql-server-transaction/

```
/*
Demonstrate how you can insert the key values added to Staff.StaffID 
into Notifications.StaffID in single transaction
*/

INSERT INTO HR.Staff ( FirstName, LastName )
OUTPUT INSERTED.StaffID, DATEADD(d,90,GETDATE()),'90-Day Review'
INTO HR.Notification
(
StaffID,
NotificationDate,
NotificationType
)
VALUES ( 'Santa','Claus');
```